# Creating resource bell distribution over dates with pandas/ Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to implement a specific resource curve calculating the distribution of budgeted working hours over two specified dates looking at just working days(Monday-Friday). This has been done in Primavera P6 but looking for a python solution.

Example of multiple resources graphed: [Multiple Resource Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuHrf.png)

These curves are based on: [Resource Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUIe5.png)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Activity ID':['XXXX-XXXX','XXXX-XXXX','XXXX-XXXX','XXXX-XXXX','XXXX-XXXX'], 
            'Resource':['Mechanical', 'Electrical ', 'Pipelines ', 'Process ', 'Project Management'], 
            'Start':['2019-01-16'   , '2019-01-17', '2019-01-18', '2019-01-21', '2019-02-17'],
            'Finish':['2019-10-02', '2019-09-05', '2019-10-02', '2019-07-18', '2019-07-26'],
            'Current Date':['2019-05-05', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-05'],                   
            'Budgeted Labor Units':[20, 300, 400, 200, 150],
            'Remaining Labor Units:':[10, 100, 200, 50, 30]})


print(df)


Activity ID            Resource       Start      Finish Current Date  \
0   XXXX-XXXX          Mechanical  2019-01-16  2019-10-02   2019-05-05   
1   XXXX-XXXX         Electrical   2019-01-17  2019-09-05   2019-05-05   
2   XXXX-XXXX          Pipelines   2019-01-18  2019-10-02   2019-05-05   
3   XXXX-XXXX            Process   2019-01-21  2019-07-18   2019-05-05   
4   XXXX-XXXX  Project Management  2019-02-17  2019-07-26   2019-05-05   

   Budgeted Labor Units  Remaining Labor Units:  
0                    20                      10  
1                   300                     100  
2                   400                     200  
3                   200                      50  
4                   150                      30
```

The goal is to input the start date and end date calculate the working days between the two and then distribute the budgeted working hours over those days based on the resource curve.
[Resource Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUIe5.png)

This would be done for all the resources and then graphed through matplotlib showing the project resource requirements.

The next step would be setting the current date and re-calculating over the remaining distribution dates with remaining labour units.
[Progressing resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WzjF.png)

I am fairly new to python so any help and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks